# Auto Completion of Usernames or groups using mentions method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, chatter-api

I have a lightning page which displays the chatter feed of a particular group. Each feed has a text input box with a "Share" button. While entering text and using the "@" mention tag, I am hoping to use the mentions method of the chatter rest api to autocomplete the username or the group name.

```
public static ConnectApi.MentionCompletionPage getMentionCompletionPage( String communityId, String queryString, string contextId){
return ConnectApi.Mentions.getMentionCompletions(communityId,queryString,contextId);
 }
```

But not sure how I need to pass the String value the user types after the mention tag dynamically  to the "query string" parameter in the apex class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways with which you can achieve this. You can either use the following code or you could use any third party lib to achieve the auto-suggest functionality that you are looking for.Its recommended to go with the vanilla approach using aura lightning framework to avoid locker issues.

> **Component / App :**

```
<aura:application controller="ChatterFeedController" access="global" extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute access="private" name="comment" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute access="private" name="queryString" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute access="private" name="results" type="Object" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.queryString}" action="{!c.getuserhandles}"/>

    <lightning:textarea name="myTextArea" value="{!v.comment}" label="What are you thinking about?" maxlength="300" onchange="{!c.listenforMentions}" />

    <div aura:id="menu" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--left slds-nubbin--top-left slds-hide">
        <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.results.haystack}" var="item">
                <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-key="{!v.results.needle}" data-value="{!item}" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" onclick="{!c.search_replace}">
                        <span data-key="{!v.results.needle}" data-value="{!item}" class="slds-truncate">{!item}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
      </div>
</aura:application>
```

> **Controller.js :**

```
({
    listenforMentions : function(component, event, helper) {
        clearTimeout(window.timer);
        window.timer = setTimeout($A.getCallback(function(){
            var commentBody = component.get("v.comment");
            var regex = new RegExp('@[a-z0-9_-]+', 'gi');
            /* Check if the comment has @handle & get the last used handle */
            if(regex.test(commentBody)){
                var handles = commentBody.match(regex);
                var querystring = handles[handles.length-1];
                component.set("v.queryString",querystring);
            }
        }),1000);
    },
    getuserhandles : function(component, event, helper) {
        var user_handle = component.get("v.queryString");
        var action = component.get("c.getMentionCompletionPage");
        action.setParams({
            "queryString" : user_handle.replace(/@/g, '') , 
            "contextId" : "0D58E00000L9sdtSAB"
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state==="SUCCESS"){
                /* show menu */
                var menu = component.find("menu");
                $A.util.toggleClass(menu, 'slds-hide');

                var possible_mentions = response.getReturnValue().mentionCompletions;
                var predictions = new Array();
                for(var i=0; i< possible_mentions.length; i++){
                    predictions.push(possible_mentions[i].name);
                }
                if(predictions.length > 0){
                    var result = {
                        "needle" : user_handle,
                        "haystack" : predictions
                    };
                    component.set("v.results",result);
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }, 
    search_replace : function(component, event, helper){
        var key = event.srcElement.dataset.key;
        var value = event.srcElement.dataset.value;
        var changed_comment = component.get("v.comment").replace(key,'@['+value+']');
        component.set("v.comment",changed_comment );
        /*hide menu*/
        var menu = component.find("menu");
        $A.util.toggleClass(menu, 'slds-hide');
    }
})
```

A timer logic is used to prevent recursive checks during the onChange event, an aura:handler looks for value change and fires the server side action callback. The response is then used to populate the menu and finnally we are performing a search and replace on the comment.

> **Apex Class:**

```
@AuraEnabled
global static ConnectApi.MentionCompletionPage getMentionCompletionPage(String queryString, string contextId){
    return ConnectApi.Mentions.getMentionCompletions(communityId,queryString,contextId);
}
```

> **Sample Output :**

Auto-Suggestions in the menu, when the user types @

[image: Suggestion]

After the user clicks on the desired suggestion.

[image: Suggestionclicked]

**Note:** An alternate approach would to pull all the usernames during init and store it inside a array and probably use Jquery auto-complete using the array, this would work as well.

Comment: P.S- I have hard coded the contextId in the action callback. the contextId is nothing but the feedId which in the context of this comment.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, although it may be nice if the nubbin was removed

Comment: The pointy part

Comment: Does this now include the updated code and image without the nubbin?

Comment: @StormBr34ker why is it not available in built with lwc? I am trying to rewrite it in lwc. I also need to notify mentioned user after posting it

Comment: @user1614862 : Why its not available inbuilt with lwc is a question for the product owners. Please check in ideaexchange.